# Replacing non unicode characters in string C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I've got a problem replacing non-unicode characters in function. I've also set     `setlocale(LC_ALL,"LITHUANIAN");`
And I'm using `<string> and <iostream> libraries`

```
void string_change()
{
    cout << "Enter text: ";
    string text;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, text);
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (check(text[i])==1)   // checking if char is in the list
            {
            text[i]='_';         // replacing char in string
            }
    }
    cout << text;
}

int check(char c)
{
    switch(c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'ą':
        case 'Ą':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'ę':
        case 'Ę':
        case 'ė':
        case 'Ė':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'į':
        case 'Į':
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'ų':
        case 'Ų':
        case 'ū':
        case 'Ū':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
}
```

with input of: "tes ąęe"
I get output: "t_s ąę_".
My desired output is: "t_s ___"
At this point I'm all lost. I imagine it has to do something with unicode characters. I'm using `Codeblocks Release 13.12  rev 9501 (2013-12-25 18:25:45)   gcc 5.2.1 Linux/unicode - 64 bit`

Comment: Yes to unicode being a potential problem. The character set and encoding of the cpp file may not be the same as the character set or encoding of the console. And you may be testing wide characters (`wchar_t`) against `char` in the switch. Might be a compiler warning over this.

Comment: off topic: [`std::set` replaces your check function with a data structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). `if (checkset.find != myset.end())` replace.

Comment: Off topic:  I recommend replacing that switch statement with an array lookup.  Place all those vowels into a character array (`wchar`?) and search the array.